# idea [08S01] Communications link failure

Tags: mysql

I just use IDEA recently and want to use IDEA to connect MySQL(8.0.12).but the IDEA indicate below

[image]

[image]

However, I use cmd could connect to my database,thus I did not configure out the problem.

[image]

I am in serah of many ways to solve this problem on tech forum but those are not working.

1. change mysql to lower version driver
2. set time_zone
3. add properties on url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of [things to check to solve the 'Communications links' failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql).

One thing in particular is to check whether your MySQL server accepts TCP connections. In your terminal, it looks like you are using named pipes.

Make sure your MySQL server allows TCP connections; check for the `bind-address` configuration in `mysql.ini` under `[mysqld]` section. Its value should be at least `127.0.0.1`, or set it as `*` to bind to all (not always a good idea).

Another point is the [skip_networking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_networking) configuration. Check if you have that, and remove and restart MySQL server. I believe this is set by default when you are installing MySQL.

(Also note that 8.0.17 is 'ancient' already).